# passing variable into JQ to select a value from the piped output

Tags: bash, shell, jq, aws-cli

below is the aws cli command that works.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers |\
   jq '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[] |
       select(.DNSName == "internal-elbdnsendpoint1.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com") |
       .LoadBalancerName, .SecurityGroups[]'
```

I am trying to get the security group for all the services (load balancers) deployed:

```
for i in `kubectl get svc -A | grep LoadB | awk '{print $5}'`; do
    aws elb describe-load-balancers |\
    jq -r --arg var $i '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[] | select(.DNSName == $var) | ...';
done
```

I tried with `"$var"`, `$var` and `[$var]`. doesn't work anything at `select(.DNSName == $var)`
but the above command doesn't work.

But again, here is my test command that worked with no issues, so really need some help finding the right command and some understanding on why the way it behaves:

```
echo '{"vikas": [{"k2": "v1"},{"k2":"v2","k3":"v3"}]}' |\
    jq -r --arg var "$i" '.vikas[] | select(.k2 == "v2") | .k2, .k3'`
```

Also, Below is a sample output for the list of load balancers for:

```
for i in `kubectl get svc -A | grep LoadB | awk '{print $5}'`; do
    echo $i
done
```

```
internal-elbdnsendpoint1.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
internal-elbdnsendpoint2.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
internal-elbdnsendpoint3.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
internal-elbdnsendpoint4.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: There is a discrepancy between `.DNSName == "internal-elbdnsendpoint.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"` and the almost-corresponding value in the sample output for the list of load balancers: `internal-elbdnsendpoint1.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Comment: those endpoints internal* were just the examples. I didnt put the actual values.

Comment: It would probably help all concerned if you followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely.